# Max. speed that a space probe can communite with the Earth?

Tags: exoplanet, space, extra-terrestrial

**Question**: *Which is the average or maximum speed of a telematically sent message that a space probe can send*? Is as simple as radio waves travel at the speed of light in a vacuum?

**Context**: I have been asked to make a first estimation about how much time is needed to send a space probe and then receive the signal.

I am supposing that the space probe is sent at $15 \ km/s$ but I have not idea of the telematic signal speed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for [Space Exploration](http://space.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Taking the speed of light will be a good approximation, as long as the signal is sent directly.

Comment: Marc, do you want to know the average or the maximum, or both? This needs to be cleared up.